# Git Feature Branch Merge to Staging from Develop Issues

Tags: git, git-flow

Currently, we have this workflow:

1. We create feature branches based on the `develop` branch (`develop` is based on the master branch)
2. We open PRs with base `develop` and after code review, we merge into `develop`
3. We want **ONLY** the approved feature branches to be moved next to `staging` branch which is exactly as our stable master at this point

**So the problem here is** when we merge the feature branch to `staging` the entire `develop` history gets merged as well (because as you know feature branches are based on `develop`).

**So the question is** how can we merge feature branches to `staging` without getting the entire `develop` history into it.

Also if we based the feature branches against `master` I think when merging to develop it may produce conflicts (if for example, 2 feature branches are having commits to same files and lines)

Please correct me on the last point if I am wrong.

**Note:** The reason for the following workflow is that we want to follow Gitflow, but the release branches from develop make our deployments wait until develop is stable to be released, so we wanted to streamline that by just getting the ready features to the release branch (staging).

Comment: You can `cherry-pick` and pick only relevant commits that you want to include. Why are you merging everything into `develop` and not only the approved feature branches?

Comment: Yes, was thinking about `cherry-pick`, I am just not confident about it, and no we merge only approved feature branches to develop, but `approved` here means code reviewed not tested, so we do testing in `develop` server, then we want to move only ready (tested) features to the staging server (which is somehow pre-production or pre-release environment), in which we test again.

I hope that clarifies the purpose of this kind-of workflow.

Comment: @Maroun so if I cherry-picked all commits from feature branches to my release branch (`staging`), then I merged that to `master` (that will result in some duplicate content commits that will have different commit hashes). Then if I merged `master` back to develop the duplication will be there, I think this can be solved if I rebased `develop` to `master`, right?

Comment: @Maroun We have a very similar process. Although I'm not completely against cherry picking to get the approved work to staging, it will be complicated with 10+ developers having to manage it. Is there any reasonable way to manage this through pull requests? What I thought would be a good solution was to create all branches from `staging` and then they are initially merged to `develop` and then later to `staging` once approved. However this creates problems in the `develop` branch where unrelated branches can effectively rollback recently merged work as it doesn't yet exist in `staging`. Ideas?